# Using Docker Swarm from two different places

Tags: docker, ipv6, ipv4, swarm

I'm trying to create a docker swarm composed with 5 nodes : 2 at my home, and 3 hosted on Scaleway. At this point, I want to use the same advertise-addr for all servers.

The problem is that I can't have the same IP adress from every place :
- clu010001 (home): has box IPv4 & IPv6
- clu010002 (home): has box IPv4 & IPv6
- clu010003 (hosted): has both IPv4 and IPv6
- clu010004 (hosted): has only IPv6
- clu010005 (hosted): has only IPv6

I had configured all nodes to allow using IPv6 according to this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ipv6/

My aim is to have only one public IPv4 (the one linked on clu010003), and to make every node communicate by using IPv6 addresses.

I can link clu010003, clu010004 and clu010005 together using `docker swarm join --token xxx [IPv6]:2377`. But when I type the same command on clu010001 and clu010002, I've this error :

```
Error response from daemon: manager stopped: can't initialize raft node: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = could not connect to prospective new cluster member using its advertised address: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

I don't really know what is blocking the whole configuration.

I noticed that if I plug clu010001 and clu010002 to the public IPv4 of clu010003, they join the cluster, but services aren't available when I'm using this IPv4 address.

Do you have some idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: I am having the same problem for the last week. Any updates? Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hello @AlexanderPaulWansiedler. No, I finally stop this Swarm thing to just my 2 nodes at home. But now I'm seeing this subject, may a VPN would solve the whole thing.

Comment: same thought here...